Finding $k$ such that the sequence defined by $s_1=k$ and $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{4s_n-1}$ is monotone increasing (or monotone decreasing)

Let $s_1=k$ and define $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{4s_n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$. Determine for what values of $k$ the sequence $(s_n)$ will be monotone increasing and for what values of $k$ it will be monotone decreasing.

This is the work I have done so far for this problem.

I know that I have to look at three case: $1/4 < k < 2-\sqrt{3}$, $2-\sqrt{3}<k<2+\sqrt{3}$, and $k>2+\sqrt{3}$. I know that for each case I have to show that the sequence is either increasing or decreasing. I think I know what’s going on in each case, I just am having a hard time proving it.
For example, when $k>2+\sqrt{3}$, the sequence is decreasing. I thought of using induction. For the base case I was able to show that $s_{2} = \sqrt{4k-1} < s_1 = k$. Now I’m on the induction step. I know that I am assuming $s_{k+1} = \sqrt{4s_{k}-1} < s_{k}$ and I need to show $s_{k+2} = \sqrt{4s_{k+1}-1} < s_{k+1} = \sqrt{4s_{k}-1}$. This is what I’ve started:
$s_{k+1} < s_k$
$4s_{k+1} < 4s_k$
$4s_{k+1}-1 < 4s_k-1$
Now I’m unsure what to do. If I knew $4s_{k+1}-1$ was greater than zero then I could conclude $\sqrt{4s_{k+1}-1} < \sqrt{4s_k-1}$.
Thank you!

Can you show when $x>2+\sqrt3$, then $2+\sqrt3<\sqrt{4x-1}<x$?

@lIlIlIlIlIlIlIlIlI I have edited the question. Thank you!

Consider two intervals $A=(2-\sqrt{3},2+\sqrt{3})$ and $B=(2+\sqrt{3},\infty)$.
Claim: If $x\in A$, then $\sqrt{4x-1}\in A$; if $x\in B$, then $\sqrt{4x-1}\in B$.
Note that $x>2-\sqrt{3}\implies \sqrt{4x-1}>\sqrt{4(2-\sqrt 3)-1}=2-\sqrt 3$ and $x<2+\sqrt 3\implies\sqrt{4x-1}<\sqrt{4(2+\sqrt 3)-1}=2+\sqrt 3$, so $x\in A\implies \sqrt{4x-1}\in A$. We also have $x>2+\sqrt 3\implies \sqrt{4x-1}>\sqrt{4(2+\sqrt 3)+1}=2+\sqrt 3$, so $x\in B\implies\sqrt{4x-1}\in B$.
Claim: If $x\in A$, then $\sqrt{4x-1}>x$; if $x\in B$, then $\sqrt{4x-1}<x$.
Consider the polynomial $x^2-4x+1$, which has roots at $2\pm \sqrt{3}$. If $x\in A$, then $x^2-4x+1<0\implies \sqrt{4x-1}>x$, where square rooting is possible since everything is positive. If $x\in B$, then $x^2-4x+1>0\implies \sqrt{4x-1}<x$, as desired.
Now we can use these tools to solve the question. Note that if $k\in A$, then each successive term of the sequence will stay in $A$, meaning each term $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{4s_n-1}>s_n$ will be greater than the previous. Meanwhile, if $k\in B$, then each successive term of the sequence will stay in $B$ and also be less than the previous.
Hence, the sequence is monotonically increasing if $k\in A$ and monotonically decreasing if $k\in B$. At $k=2\pm\sqrt 3$, it can be verified that the sequence stays constant.
But what about when $k<2-\sqrt 3$? Well, we can use the same trick in the second claim and note that $x^2-4x+1>0\implies\sqrt{4x-1}<x$, so the series continues to decrease. But since the series cannot converge to a limit below $2-\sqrt{3}$ (think about how one would prove this rigorously), the function must reach $s_n<\frac{1}{4}$ at some point, causing the terms to become complex and therefore breaking the definition of "increasing" and "decreasing" in this context.

This makes sense! Thank you so much!
